# Whats the privilege required to access ALL_ARGUMENTS in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, privileges

I want to know which privilege is required to access the table ALL_ARGUMENTS in Oracle? There is any specific one?

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_ARGUMENTS
```

Searched on web but found nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ALL_ARGUMENTS` table is returned when we execute this:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dba_tab_privs WHERE grantee='PUBLIC' and table_name like 'ALL_ARGUMENTS'
```

We see a value of `PUBLIC` as the grantee. That means, PUBLIC has SELECT privilege.

Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TTSYS/systemtables.htm#TTSYS348

There may be other tables in SYS, for which this is not true: Then, `ADMIN` or `SELECT ANY TABLE` privileges are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, anyone can see ALL_ARGUMENTS. For that matter, anyone can see any ALL_ data dictionary view.

It will show you YOUR arguments, and any argument for an object you are also able to view based on your privilege level.

This security check is why querying DBA_ views is always (generally) faster than querying ALL_ views - because it just shows EVERY SINGLE ARGUMENT regardless of object privileges.

Not every view has an ALL_ and a DBA_ version.

From the [DOCS](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/datadict.htm#CNCPT1209)